How to get a list of all URLs in history starting by some prefix in Firefox?
When I type the start of an URL in Firefox, I get an auto-completion of maybe 10 choices.
But on some websites like professional web apps, you may have 30 or 50 links of interest to you and if it doesn't appear in auto-completion, you have to navigate in the web app and lose time.
How to find all these URLs without writing a script that will read the data of Firefox?
Examples of features I've seen before but I don't find now:
You type: https://example.com/.
Currently Firefox will answer with:
https://example.com/a/a
https://example.com/a/b
https://example.com/A/a
https://example.com/b/a
https://example.com/b/b

If you have many entries starting with: https://example.com/a/, current results suggested by Firefox are useless when you want something starting with https://example.com/b/.
You may say "Then just type b/", and I will answer "When you have many nesting levels and you just remember part of it..., you cannot type b/. You have to explore.".
If instead of that Firefox answered with:
https://example.com/a/
https://example.com/A/
https://example.com/b/
https://example.com/B/
...

You would have a tree view of you URLs and stop having a useless feature above a certain threshold of URLs.
Maybe, I'm the first one to think about it or ask for this in free software.
But somehow, I think I've seen this.
I will make a feature request on Firefox.

Wht is "prefix" exactly? What are "professional web apps"? You should be as detailed as possible and provide examples.

Professional web apps are web apps used by employees, it is not web apps used by netflix viewers..., they can have hundreds of screens...

You can display the history in Firefox by menu History > Show All History
or bu pressing Ctrl+H.
You can type your string into the search field (regex not allowed) and
press Enter.
If you wish to select all the URLs, this is a bit more complicated.
The method I found is this:

Right-click the first entry, but immediately press Esc
Press Ctrl+A to select-all
Press Ctrl+C to copy the URLs to the clipboard.


Hello, thanks for your answer, for my use case it is not as useful as expected because the feature only shows the title of the webpage: see here for a screenshot https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1890012 :)

Strange, for me it got the URLs, not the titles. I have no idea what's the difference, except that I use Firefox only rarely and have very few extensions installed.

Ctrl+H, then use the menu to select type of list, and then use @harrymc 's answer for more....


Thanks for trying but no ;). It is not that bad, in the sense that View > By Site is almost usable. But unfortunately, there is still the problem that it shows titles instead of URLs. Take a look at my feature requests on bugzilla :).
